# Is there any way to unbind escape from opening the autocompletion menu in XCode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2

I'm coming from predominantly using VIM for everything, and so I have a habit of hitting escape basically any time I finish typing.  Is there anyway to ONLY unbind the autocomplete menu from appearing when hitting escape?  If I remove the 'cancel' keybind for esc, then it stops popping up the autocomplete menu, but I can't cancel anything and instead I get upside down question marks whenever I hit escape.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Preferences->Text Editing->General tab->Code Completion->Escape key shows code completions.

Uncheck it and you're set. Here, have a pic with the obligatory hand-drawn red 'circle':

[image: Screenshot[][1]]

Comment: Fantastic, this has been driving me nuts.  Thanks!